# How to limit how much the user can resize a JavaFX window?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, resize, fxml

I am looking for ways to limit how much a user can resize the main window of my application, without preventing resizing completely. Specifically, I want to set minimum width and height for the window, and you'd think `minWidth` and `minHeight` would achieve this, but apparently they do not.

The root element of my window (declared in fxml) looks like this:

```java
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="com.my.module.FXMLController"
      minWidth="400.0">
    <!-- ... -->
</VBox>
```

But all that `minWidth` seems to be doing is setting up the initial size of the window. If I try to resize the window as a user, i can get it as small as the title bar decorations, which is not ideal.

What's the correct way to do this, and is there a declarative way, as opposed to forcibly restoring the window's state after the user resizes it "illegally"? Furthermore, I would like to do this through the FXML document rather than in code, if possible.

For context, this is JavaFX 12 on JVM 12, I'm on Windows 10.
I had found another similar question on SO but it's unanswered and rather old.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stage has width & height property and you can use Stage.setMinWidth() and .setMinHeight().

You can also listen resize event like this,

```
mainStage.widthProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue)->{
    if(newValue.intValue() < 400.0) {
        mainStage.setResizable(false);
        mainStage.setWidth(400);
        mainStage.setResizable(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh I see, so the stage is what governs this. I thought I could do it from the scene itself.